# Ajax Loading panel not displaying?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I've got a Loading panel for Ajax that I'm trying to get to display. I took the code from another project where this works but it's using LESS, Bootstrap 3, and FontAwesome 4. The project I'm try to apply it to is Bootstrap 4, SASS, and FontAwesome 5.

Right not I just want it to display so I can verify what it looks like and that it's working correctly and then I'll hide it by hooking it up with an Ajax call. What is being displayed on the page is just the words "Processing, please wait..." in the standard font all the way to the left which tells me the CSS is not getting applied. When I inspect say the line for "ajax-loading-panel" in the Dev Tools I'm not seeing any of the styles that should be applied on that element.

I've been struggling to understand how the specificity of SASS works and the order of where I need to put my CSS in the SASS files. I have a feeling that is part of the problem.

This is the HTML and CSS. I initially put the CSS in my site.scss file but also tried putting it in the _theme.scss file as well thinking it wasn't picking it up in the site.scss. I confirmed the CSS is being written out to my site.css file that is compiled so I would think it is available.

HTML

```
<div id="divLoading" class="ajax-loading-wrapper">
    <div class="ajax-loading-div">
        <span class="ajax-loading-text">
            Processing, please wait...
        </span>
        <span class="ajax-loading-icon fas fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (and I see this when I look at the compiled .css file)

```
/*==============  AJAX LOADING PANEL  =====================*/
.ajax-loading-wrapper  {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #666;
    z-index: 30001;
    filter:  opacity(0.85);
}

.ajax-loading-div  {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 7em;
    padding-top: 2.3em;
    width: 20em;
    margin-left: -10em;
    padding-left: 2.1em;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.ajax-loading-text  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 20%;
    color: white;
}

.ajax-loading-icon  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 39%;
    color: white;
}
```

This is my site.scss file.

```
   @import "scss/_custom-variables.scss";
    @import "bootstrap/bootstrap.scss";
    @import "scss/_theme.scss";

/*==============  AJAX LOADING PANEL  =====================*/
.ajax-loading-wrapper  {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #666;
    z-index: 30001;
    filter:  opacity(0.85);
}

.ajax-loading-div  {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 7em;
    padding-top: 2.3em;
    width: 20em;
    margin-left: -10em;
    padding-left: 2.1em;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.ajax-loading-text  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 20%;
    color: white;
}

.ajax-loading-icon  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 39%;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Have you used Inspect or a debug console to see what CSS is loading? The CSS looks correct, I would be concerned with ensuring the file is properly linked in the HTML.

Comment: I have looked at the CSS in Chrome's Dev Tools and I'm not seeing the CSS. It's like it's not getting applied even though it's in the site.css file. I also created a simple button with a font awesome icon and that works. I'm a little baffled at what's going on. I'm sure it's something I'm not doing correctly.

Comment: Did you resolve this? Can you confirm that the CSS file is being loaded by that particular page?

Comment: Yes, I did get it figured out. I was looking a for so long I was overlooking a simple stupid mistake. Left out the # in the selector. Felt like a dumb a$$ once I saw it.